# closing issue with modal in modal - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a customer visits list page, in which add visit invokes a bootstrap popup ("#Pop1") to record visit details. In the modal, I have provision to add new customer (on the fly), which in turn opens another popup ("#Pop2") to capture new customer details.

On successful save of the new customer (via AJAX) I show an alert (browser alert) and close new customer popup using `$("#Pop2").hide();.` On successful save of visit, I show an alert and close the add visit popup using `$("#Pop1").hide();.`

I have a couple of issues in this context.

1. (critical) Pop1 -> Pop2 -> Save -> Save. In this scenario, it returns to the listing page, but the page is not accessible. a transparent layer (that came with Pop1) was still overlay on the page. I need to refresh entire page to add another visit.
2. When I close the Pop2 using close button, it closes both the popups.

Is there a piece of JS or CSS I need to apply to get this work properly?

Comment: Is close your custom button?if yes what code had you written

Comment: It is the same that appear in all popup examples... <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `$("#Pop2").hide();` use `$("#Pop2").modal('hide');`

same goes for `Pop1` also